# Regex to match any character including newline

Tags: regular-expression

I frequently find myself trying to do transformations like

```
  author    = {{foo
                bar}},
```

to

```
  author    = {foo
                bar},
```

and I can't find a regex to match the part in between the curly braces.

```
%s/{{\(.*\)}}/{\1}/g
```

doesn't work since `.` does not match newlines. But `[\.\r]` or something doesn't seem to work either. I tried `[\s\S]` as well to match whitespace and non-whitespace, but to no avail.

Comment: I know this is old, but I think with surround.vim you can do `ds{`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You should use `\_.\{-}` instead of `.*`.

`\_.` matches any character including end-of-line. However, as `:h \_.` warns, using it with `*` will match all text to the end of the buffer.

`\{-}` is similar to `*`, matching 0 or more instances of the proceeding atom. But it matches **as few as possible** instead of as many as possible. This makes `\{-}` safe if your example pattern appears more than once. For example:

```
author = {{foo
           bar}},

editor = {{buz
           baz}},
```

Using `%s/{{\(\_.*\)}}/{\1}/g` changes the starting double brace for author, but the closing double brace for editor. Since `*` matches as many atoms as possible, the pattern matches until the last double brace it finds. This results in the following:

```
author = {foo
           bar}},

editor = {{buz
           baz},
```

However, using `%s/{{\(\_.\{-}\)}}/{\1}/g` gives the desired result for both author and editor as it stops searching at the first double brace it finds:

```
author = {foo
           bar},

editor = {buz
           baz},
```

Comment: Good point, I'll mark this as accepted.

Comment: +1 used it to finish my regex for replacing domain names in a db dump that contained serialized data so that it won't corrupt it :) For those interested: https://github.com/RensTillmann/cli-common-commands/blob/master/vim.md

Answer (score 1):

Turns out one must use `\_.*` instead of `.`.